# How to retrieve value from json output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to json. I have json output that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "employees": {
            "education": "BE\/B.Tech"
        },
        "0": {
            "count": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "employees": {
            "education": "MBA"
        },
        "0": {
            "count": "3"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to retrieve the employee's education and the count. I have tried but i am not able to retrieve the values.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste the code that you tried using to retrieve this JSON output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your JSON string is in a variable `$json`, it goes like this:

```
var employees_list = JSON.parse($json);
```

Then you can access the information via:

```
employees_list[0].employees.education // gives you "BE\/B.Tech"
// and
employees_list[0]["0"].count // gives you 1.
```

You can also loop over the array and access all the different `education` this way.

**Update:**

To better demonstrate which expression accesses which information:

```
[                                      // employees_list
    {                                  // employees_list[0]
        "employees": {                 // employees_list[0].employees
            "education": "BE\/B.Tech"  // employees_list[0].employees.education
        },
        "0": {                         // employees_list[0]["0"]
            "count": "1"               // employees_list[0]["0"].count
        }
    }, 
    {                                  // employees_list[1]
        "employees": {                 // employees_list[1].employees
            "education": "MBA"         // employees_list[1].employees.education
        },
        "0": {                         // employees_list[1]["0"]
            "count": "3"               // employees_list[1]["0"].count
        }
    }
]
```

Generally `employees_list[0].employees` is the same as `employees_list[0]["employees"]` but this does not work for numbers, because properties and variables are not allowed to start with numbers. So you can **only** use `employees_list[0].["0"]` **and not** `employees_list[0].0`.

---

The structure of your JSON string looks a bit strange though. You should consider to structure it differently if you can.

For example:

```
[
    {
        "education": "BE\/B.Tech",
        "count": "1"
    },
    {
        "education": "MBA"
        "count": "3"
    }
]
```

The `"0"` key in your original JSON string seems to serve no purpose and just complicates the access.

Comment: I know the output looks strange. 
var employees_list;
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
       employees_list = JSON.parse(data);   
    showAlert();
});

function showAlert() {
    alert(employees_list[0].employees.education);
}

I tried this but does not work.

Comment: @Nick: If you use `getJSON` then you don't need to parse it. It is already parsed. `data[0].employees.education` should work.