# How to retrieve the values from json

Tags: java, xml, json

I am converting xml message into json object and  i want to read all the values from json object how can i read all the values Example-pfirstname="Anssi"; like this i want to read all the values in the json formated string.
I am using jsonobject to convert

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml1);

{
"event": {
    "eventpermits": {
        "eventpermit": {
            "pfirstname": "Anssi",
            "pmodifydate": {
                "minute": 20,
                "second": 40,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 11,
                "day": 21
            },
            "pplates": "ABC123",
            "genddate": {
                "minute": 59,
                "second": 59,
                "month": 12,
                "year": 9999,
                "hour": 23,
                "day": 31
            },
            "gname": "Visy",
            "permitreason": 2,
            "penddate": {
                "minute": 0,
                "second": 0,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 17,
                "day": 21
            },
            "accesscheckdate": {
                "minute": 20,
                "second": 45,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 11,
                "day": 21
            },
            "pstartdate": {
                "minute": 0,
                "second": 0,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 12,
                "day": 20
            },
            "id": 13,
            "selected": 1,
            "plastname": "Huttunen",
            "gstartdate": {
                "minute": 0,
                "second": 59,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 0,
                "day": 20
            },
            "points": 1,
            "eventnumber": 4,
            "gaccesslevel": 0,
            "accesscheckid": 17,
            "pid": 4,
            "pcreatorname": "VisyXMLGate",
            "pcpallowed": 1,
            "gcheckpointallowed": 1,
            "gid": 1,
            "pdeletedate": {
                "minute": 0,
                "second": 0,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 0,
                "day": 21
            },
            "povt": "X2",
            "pcompany": "Visy",
            "pcreationdate": {
                "minute": 19,
                "second": 27,
                "month": 6,
                "year": 2012,
                "hour": 11,
                "day": 21
            }
        }
    },
    "accessdecision": {
        "cppolicy": "OPENFORPERMIT",
        "id": 17,
        "permitreason": 2,
        "date": {
            "minute": 20,
            "second": 45,
            "month": 6,
            "year": 2012,
            "hour": 11,
            "day": 21
        },
        "eventnumber": 4,
        "frontplate": "ABC123"
    },
    "permitreason": 2,
    "checkpoint": {
        "messagedirection": "IN",
        "id": 1,
        "direction": "IN",
        "tag": "IN1",
        "name": "Entrance 1",
        "policy": "OPENFORPERMIT",
        "sourceareaid": 1,
        "targetareaid": 2
    },
    "permitid": 4,
    "frontlicenseplates": {
        "licenseplate": {
            "formatted": "ABC123",
            "nationality": "FIN",
            "unformatted": "",
            "confidence": 1.1
        }
    },
    "date": {
        "minute": 18,
        "second": 29,
        "month": 6,
        "year": 2012,
        "hour": 11,
        "day": 21
    },
    "eventnumber": 4,
    "ovt": "VisyAccessGate"
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all the values"? Which values do you want?

Comment: It means under eventpermit i want to read minute,hour,second,month,year like that.

Comment: Is this fixed pattern/format of json ? or may be vary on time ?

Comment: No it is fixed format it will not vary

Comment: so this is JSON you want to convert it to xml ? right ?

Comment: @user3145373 ツ :He converted it from XML

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276838/how-to-retrieve-value-from-json-output is this what you want

Comment: I am in a confusion that can you help me out this question i.e., I am directly reading xml message using xpath and reading values and i am trying to do with json because of light weight object so which one is best approach to read values

Answer (score 0):

According to your Json string structure, all are formatted with `JSONObject {}` and no `JSONArray []` containing.

Here is example to get `pfirstname` value, and **like this way, you can try other values yourself.**

```
//firstly get 'event' JSONObject
JSONObject event = xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("event");

//from 'event' JSONObject, get 'eventpermits' JSONObject as it is enclosing with {}
JSONObject eventpermits = event.getJSONObject("eventpermits");

//to get 'eventpermit' JSONObject
JSONObject eventpermit = eventpermits.getJSONObject("eventpermit");

//to get JSONObject of 'pmodifydate' AND one string value of 'pfirstname'
JSONObject pmodifydate = eventpermit.getJSONObject("pmodifydate");

//string value of 'pfirstname'
String pfirstname = eventpermit.getString("pfirstname");
```

When you access value with its type, according to your JSON string structure, you can use the right accessor with field name -

- getString()
- getBoolean()
- getInt(), getLong(), getDouble()

See api [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Comment: I am in a confusion that can you help me out this question i.e., I am directly reading xml message using xpath and reading values and i am trying to do with json because of light weight object so which one is best approach to read values .

Comment: @Vskiran I prefer the way of xml string converting to JSON object and then accessing the required values. It is elegant and easy to maintain code and make readiness, than `xpath` usage. Or you can raise about your confusion as a new post !!!!

Comment: Yes Thank you @Born For that i need to wait for 90 more minutes for a new post